# How can I inform a reviewer that their comments have been addressed

Tags: github

On GitHub, when a colleague leaves a review on my PR and "Requests Changes", is there a way for me to mark the PR with "changes made"?

This should ideally send a notification to the reviewer to let them know that they can look again at the PR.

[image]

Comment: This would be a useful Github feature! For now, I just comment on the pull request and mention the colleague who should take another look at the PR.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing this answer, there is no built-in way of explicitly notifying the reviewer when their changes have been addressed.

As Adil B mentioned, the best workaround is probably just to @ the reviewer in a comment so they get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an email when there's a change in the PR then maybe create a Gmail filter and introduce a practice to follow up those emails with the team.
I'm also looking for a solution to get quicker response in PR reviews..